# ad hoc distribution on ipod touch

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, provisioning, adhoc

I am developing a game for the iPhone and have at least 8 people to beta test for me using ad-hoc distribution. I created a provisioning file with all of there phones id's and built my app using that provisioning file.

I emailed out the app and that mobileprovisioning file to the people. Three of them have ipod touch devices. It seems to install properly on the iphones. But two of the users of the ipod touch's tries installing it and had problems (the third can't try till tonight), the dragging of the files seems to be accepted by itunes, then during the sync the app is rejected as unauthorized (the message is something similar to "the application could not be verified").

Any ideas of what could be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this 
I first had to clear all my certificates and recreate them making sure the email address and name matched exactly what the developer website thinks they are.

Then I had to create an Ad-Hoc distribution profile (before I only created a development profile)

I found the answer on this [site](http://www.gqadonis.com/?p=47)

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this happen before with iPhone's as well.  I think that what is happening is that sometimes the app is trying to sync before the provisioning profile.  Oftentimes a second sync will allow the app to install just fine.  One other thing you may have your users try is to install the profile and the app via the iPhone Configuration Utility (http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/).

Comment: Had them try both, no change.